# nested switch control flow in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

could you please suggest !!! The scenario is like below: I tried a multiple switch, case statements, but couldn't made..

```
switch 1
case 'YESS'
{
% curly braces are just to denote the scope of case 'YESS'
.....code      
switch 2
case 'Yes'
from here Can I jump again to the start of switch(1),case 'YESS' ??
case 'No'
%% some message 
end
}
case'NOO'
%% some message 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

However you did not explain clearly what you are looking for, how about using a function as follows:

```
function main
prompt = 'Do you want more? Y/N [Y]: ';
str1 = askYesNoQuestion(prompt);
switch str1
    case 'Y'
        prompt2 = 'Asking to make sure? Y/N [Y]: ';
        str2 = askYesNoQuestion(prompt2);
        disp(str2);
    case 'N'
        disp('OK no problem!');
end
end


function str = askYesNoQuestion(prompt)
str = input(prompt,'s');
if isempty(str)
    str = 'Y';
end
switch str
    case 'Y'
        disp('you said yes');
    case 'N'
        disp('you said no')
end
end
```

You can save the whole code in an m-file with name `main.m` and run it.

Comment: There will be two folders of sound- of course different category (say Machine sound and human sound). I extract features of all files in a folder at a time, save the features in a table- matrix, a message box ask for next folder for feature extraction, if user say yes. I have to repeat the procedure as for first folder ... Its the exact scenario. I am able to do this for first folder, but not to the second folder... Expected some help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell matlab to keep looping

```
  keepLooping = true;
    while keepLooping 
    switch 1
    case 'YESS'
    keepLooping = false; %% exit switch 1

      switch 2
        case 'Yes' %% back to switch 1
        keepLooping = true; %% re-enter switch 1

        case 'No'  %% some message 
        keepLooping = false %% exit switch 1
      end
    case'NOO' %% some message 
    keepLooping = false; %% exit switch 1
    end
    end
```

or in alternative, to jump already inside the 'YESS' case:

```
isYesOrNo = 'YESS'
      keepLooping = true;
        while keepLooping 
        switch isYesOrNo
        case 'YESS'
        keepLooping = false; %% exit switch 1
          switch 2
            case 'Yes' %% back to switch 1
            keepLooping = true; %% re-enter switch 1
            isYesOrNo = 'YESS' %% re-enter 'YESS'

            case 'No'  %% some message 
            keepLooping = false %% exit switch 1
          end
        case'NOO' %% some message 
        keepLooping = false; %% exit switch 1
        end
        end
```